# Redirecting UDP to local port the reply packet isn't SNATed, w/ iptables

Tags: iptables, nat, udp, iptables-redirect

I ran `dnscrypt-proxy` or `tor` on Linux listning on `[::]:1053` to server DNS. I wanted to make all my Linux host's DNS queries transparently use that proxy.

This is what I found from Internet how we transparent proxy UDP traffic:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT--to-ports 1053
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:1053
```

(`-j REDIRECT` is equal to `-j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:`)

Didn't work. My browser can't open URLs, and `nslookup` and `dig` say:

```
;; reply from unexpected source: 192.168.3.60#1053, expected 192.168.3.1#53
```

(`192.168.3.1` is in my `/etc/resolv.conf`)

I saw on wireshark that **the reply packet from DNS proxy wasn't SNATed, but  it should be SNATed**.

And this is `conntrack -E`:

```
[NEW] udp      17 30 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=35954 dport=35954 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=35954 dport=35954
[NEW] udp      17 30 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=59799 dport=59799 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=59799 dport=59799
[NEW] udp      17 30 src=192.168.3.60 dst=192.168.3.1 sport=34825 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=192.168.3.60 sport=1053 dport=34825
[NEW] udp      17 30 src=192.168.3.60 dst=192.168.3.60 sport=1053 dport=34825 [UNREPLIED] src=192.168.3.60 dst=192.168.3.60 sport=34825 dport=1053
```

But then strangely, **if I make proxy listen on `127.0.0.1` instead of `[::]`, it works.**  I saw on wireshark the reply packet correctly SNATed. And `dig` and `nslookup` can get reply from transparent DNS proxy.

This is `conntract -E` when proxy listen on `127.0.0.1`:

```
   [NEW] udp      17 30 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=58584 dport=58584 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 sport=58584 dport=58584
   [NEW] udp      17 30 src=::1 dst=::1 sport=39482 dport=39482 [UNREPLIED] src=::1 dst=::1 sport=39482 dport=39482
   [NEW] udp      17 30 src=192.168.3.60 dst=192.168.3.1 sport=38165 dport=53 [UNREPLIED] src=127.0.0.1 dst=192.168.3.60 sport=1053 dport=38165
[UPDATE] udp      17 30 src=192.168.3.60 dst=192.168.3.1 sport=38165 dport=53 src=127.0.0.1 dst=192.168.3.60 sport=1053 dport=38165
```

While TCP doesn't encounter such issue (`dnscrypt-proxy` also serves TCP). TCP reply packet always correctly SNATed.

So what is going on? Am I doing something wrong with UDP NAT? I want DNS proxy listen on `0.0.0.0` or `[::]` and transparently proxy my Linux host's DNS queries.

Comment: Of you get that error back it is not transparent per se.

Comment: Found a similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323758/iptables-redirect-all-udp-packets-including-established) not solved

Comment: your OUTPUT rule needs exceptions, else you're redirecting your transparent DNS proxy over itself when it does queries itself.

Comment: @A.B yeah, thanks for tip. However `dnscrypt-proxy` doesn't have to connect to port 53 to query.

Comment: meanwhile I realize this is similar the question I answered later: [Redirect all outgoing DNS queries to local stub resolver at 127.0.0.1:53](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510781/redirect-all-outgoing-dns-queries-to-local-stub-resolver-at-127-0-0-153/510808#510808). My explanation about UDP stands the same. Whatever the behaviour adapt to it and SNAT the flow.

Comment: @garywill I also answered the question you told was not solved, but I believe it's not related to your case

Comment: After updating my Linux packages, no more problems. Maybe they fixed that bug?