# Using iptables to redirect all docker outbound traffic back into container

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, container

I've been stuck on this problem all day and am keeping my fingers crossed some iptables expert reads this and can help me please.

I would like to force all my docker containers's outbound traffic to go through a socks5 proxy.

This is the closest I've come:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -s 172.20.0.0/16 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:12345
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 172.20.0.0/16 -j REDSOCKS
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 172.20.0.0/16 -j REDSOCKS
```

It works almost perfectly, but the socks5 proxy is unable to tell the originating IP address.

The remote address is always '127.0.0.1'

Is there any way I can keep the originating IP address?

## Example Scenario

1. I have applied the iptables rules above to my docker host
2. I have a docker container with the address `172.20.0.2`
3. Inside that container, I do a curl to example.com
4. The traffic is forwarded to `172.17.0.1:12345` (the docker host machine)
5. The server running on `12345` shows the remote IP address as being '127.0.0.1'
6. I would like the remote IP address to show as `172.20.0.2`

Thank to anyway who can try and help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

From a network perspective, if source IP is equal to destination IP, it results to a security issue known as [Land Attack](https://www.imperva.com/learn/ddos/land-attacks/).

Answer (score 0):

> I have applied the iptables rules above to my docker host

On host, `-t nat -A OUTPUT` redirects your host's outbound traffic. You don't need that if you just want to redirect container's traffic. Using `-t nat -I PREROUTING` is enough to redirect container's traffic.

And these are some tips you could try, not sure. Hope would help:

- Since that's the host's iptables, try modify `-j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.1:12345` to `-j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:12345`
- `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT` to allow input traffics from containers. I guess your host didn't allow so the originating IP was always (and could only be) 127.0.0.1
- socks5 proxy? You need a proxy protocol bridge to use socks5 with iptables.

  ```
  container -> host -> redsocks to socks5 bridge -> socks5
  ```
- Lastly, if it still doesn't work, it could be linux's bug on NAT, like what I encountered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492937/redirecting-udp-to-local-port-the-reply-packet-isnt-snated-w-iptables). That issue solved after I upgraded Linux. I don't know, just guess