# IPTables to limit high "Call-Per-Second" and redirect to another program (same machine)

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, sip

I'm looking for a way to "control" high volume of SIP VoIP INVITEs (UDP) per second (Call Per Seconds) at iptables level in my VoIP server reaching port 5060.
What i need to do is limit amount of INVITE's per second to a certain rate (for example 20 cps), if i receive a high volume of CPS to the server, i need to redirect them to another port (for example UDP/5090) in the same machine where another program is runnig, to answer them with SIP message "603 Decline".  Is this possible?
So far i'm a little bit lost with a lot of answers to similar questions... do i need to use --limit?, connlimit?, hitcount??...
Along with this, is possible to do this by source ip address?
Conceptually I was thinking something like this... if is possible:

```
INPUT
iptables --append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW --jump RATE-LIMIT

RATE-LIMIT
iptables --append RATE-LIMIT --match limit --limit 20/sec --limit-burst 20 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append RATE-LIMIT --jump DECLINE-INVITE

DECLINE-INVITE
iptables --append DECLINE-INVITE [how to redirect to port udp 5090]
```

Thanks!
Ricardo

Answer (score 1):

First, let's take a look at the [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) schematic:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

At the step where OP is trying to operate: *filter*/INPUT it's too late to do what's intended, the occasion to do DNAT had to be done before the routing decision, in *nat*/PREROUTING.

So this must be earlier, and for some other cases it could have been needed to use two different tables: *mangle*/PREROUTING for some special test, and *nat*/PREROUTING for the port redirection, with a mark on the packet to communicate the intent from the *mangle* table to the *nat* table. Actually such cases would be very complex, probably involve conntrack zones in the *raw* table and never work with simple setups (here's such an example: [IPTables redirect all UDP packets including ESTABLISHED](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323758/iptables-redirect-all-udp-packets-including-established))

---

Here, *nat*/PREROUTING will be enough. That's because only the packets starting a new flow (state *NEW*) are checked for OP's case, and that's exactly what already happens with the *nat* table: only packets in state *NEW* are seen (as reminded in the schematic), and every other packets will follow the NAT decision that was done. So this block: `--match conntrack --ctstate NEW` becomes redundant in any *nat* table rule: it's always true. The *limit* match has no restriction and can be used in any table/chain.

In the end:

- add a filter for UDP port 5060 to not affect anything else
- no *conntrack* match needed here
- as a reminder, `-j ACCEPT` in the *nat* table just means "don't do any NAT for this case"
- DECLINE-INVITE isn't really needed, but I'll leave it as used by OP
- as the DNAT target used with a port requires a protocol, `-p udp` must be added again even if only 5060/UDP packets hit this rule.
- you can't easily test the result from the local system: the local system uses the path OUTPUT -> ... loopback ... -> PREROUTING -> INPUT. In the PREROUTING phase, the first incoming packet is matching the flow just created in OUTPUT before it was looped back, so it won't appear in NEW state anymore and won't see the *nat*/PREROUTING chain and no DNAT will be done there. DNAT can still be done immediately in OUTPUT by duplicating (and adapting adequately) these rules in *nat*/OUTPUT. Anyway I'm sure there are additional caveats for the local case. Do tests from remote (or from a connected container or network namespace) instead.

```
iptables -t nat -N RATE-LIMIT
iptables -t nat -N DECLINE-INVITE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 5060 -j RATE-LIMIT
iptables -t nat -A RATE-LIMIT -m limit --limit 20/sec --limit-burst 20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A RATE-LIMIT -j DECLINE-INVITE
iptables -t nat -A DECLINE-INVITE -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination :5090
```